# How to set a "loading..." text in vlc web plugin

Tags: html, activex, vlc, libvlc

I try the following code to set a text in vlc activex but it doesn't work any help is welcome.

```html
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" 
       pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
       version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"
       width="300px"  
       height="300px" 
       id="vlc" 
       windowless="true" 
       loop="yes" 
       autoplay="no"
       text="loading..."
       enablejavascript="true" 
       allowfullscreen="false" 
       target="rtp://@:port/">
</embed>
```

Comment: Do you know about [WebChimera plugin](http://www.webchimera.org)? - It's much more flexable in GUI customization than original Vlc plugin.

Comment: WebChimera doesn't has a "text" parameter

Comment: It don't need it, it has full featured Qml engine + JavaScript engine inside. I.e. it could have absolutely different UI, you just need use different .qml files. For example compare demos on  http://www.webchimera.org/demos/ and http://rsatom.github.io/WebChimera/demos/basic/basic_1.htm - they are absolutely different, but it all the same plugin, just different .qml

Answer (score 1):

According to Vlc Web Plugin sources [here](http://git.videolan.org/?p=npapi-vlc.git;a=blob;f=activex/plugin.cpp;hb=HEAD#l819) and [here](http://git.videolan.org/?p=npapi-vlc.git;a=blob;f=common/win32_fullscreen.cpp;hb=HEAD#l653), there are no way to draw any custom text within Vlc ActiveX.
You still have option to use [Marque object](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/#Marquee_Object) but don't sure if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done with WebChimera (which is based on libVLC.dll, so it can play any VLC supported video/audio types).

As you mentioned in the comment, WebChimera does not have a "text" parameter, this is because WebChimera Player has a [jQuery like JS architecture](http://wiki.webchimera.org/Player_JavaScript_API). So to set the opening text you'll need to use this JS code:

```
wjs("#player_wrapper").addPlayer({ id: "webchimera", theme: "sleek", autoplay: 1 });

wjs("#webchimera").addPlaylist([video-url]);

wjs("#webchimera").qmlLoaded(function() {
    wjs("#webchimera").setOpeningText("hello world");
});
```

*Where [video-url] is the url of your video.* [View the Example Online](http://editor.webchimera.org/example_setopeningtext)

Documentation Links:

[.setOpeningText() Wiki Page](http://wiki.webchimera.org/.setOpeningText())

[WebChimera Player JS API](http://wiki.webchimera.org/Player_JavaScript_API)

Comment: Just one note: WebChimera Player is wrapper around WebChimera Plugin API. So you could use it "as is" if it well suited for you, or you could go further and customize it as you wish or make your own player from scratch over WebChimera Plugin API. It's all Open Source, and almost all possible there. Just try.